# Get top level directory within the zipfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-zipfile

I have the following structure within a zipped file "test.zip"

- `JOU=00335/VOL=2019.30/ISU=9-10/ART=9812/data.xml`
- `JOU=00335/VOL=2019.30/ISU=9-10/ART=9813/data.xml`
- `JOU=00335/VOL=2019.30/ISU=9-10/ART=9814/data.xml`

There are multiple top level folders like `JOU=00336`,`JOU=00337` etc.

I want to count the top level folders.

I have the following code which gives me a count of all XML files zipped in test.zip.

```
        with ZipFile("test.zip", "r") as f:
            print(len(f.namelist()))
```

Not sure how to count just the top level folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the paths to get the first element in them, and count those unique ones with a `set`:

```
top = {item.split('/')[0] for item in f.namelist()}
print(len(top))
```